# Resultant list of hibernate select query does get cast to the corresponding bean class

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

The following query was generated by hibernate

```
Select sum(B.c_rejected_count) as y0_,B.c_date as y1_,B.c_node_site_id as y2_, 
A.c_sccp_addr as y3_ from tb_sccp_addr A inner join tb_dm_sccp_rej_day B on 
A.c_sccp_addr_id=B.c_sccp_addr_fk  group by A.c_date, A.c_node_site_id,       
B.c_sccp_addr, B.c_sccp_addr_id ;
```

My Beanclass has following data:

```
private Date date;
private long rejectedCount;
private int nodeSiteId;
private String sccpAddress;
```

when I cast the resultant list of select query to my beanclass, I get a  cast exception

```
java.lang.ClassCastException
```

Please identify what is going wrong and how to solve it

I am using Java reflection

//function initialises select query

```
private void initializeSelectQuery()
    {
        log(Level.DEBUG, "Entering initializeSelectQuery");
        Class classname = beanclass.getMappedClass();
        crit = hibernateSession.createCriteria(classname);

               if(group.getAggregate().equals("SUM"))
        {
                       projectionList.add(Projections.sum(beanDefinition
               .getPropertyForColumn(group.getColumnName())));
             }
               else
               {
                     projectionList.add(Projections.groupProperty(beanDefinition
              .getPropertyForColumn(group.getColumnName())));
               }
                  crit.setProjection(projectionList);
        crit.setMaxResults(10); 
       }


public List executeSelectQuery() {
    log(Level.DEBUG, "Entering executeSelectQuery");

    List datalist = null;

    try {
        tx = hibernateSession.beginTransaction();
        if (crit != null) {
            datalist = crit.list();
        }
        tx.commit();

    } catch (MappingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    } catch (HibernateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    log(Level.DEBUG, "Exiting executeSelectQuery");
    return datalist;

}
```

Comment: Show us your code. We don't even know what the HQL query looks like.

Comment: More-info-needed-mode: ON :) Post your stack trace at least

Comment: This error occur when i am using group by

Comment: that was obvious, seen your generated query. Post your code and the exception stack strace, otherwise you won't get much help... :)

Comment: java.lang.ClassCastException
 at java.lang.Class.cast(Unknown Source)
 at com.mavenir.data.migration.Transformers.SimpleTransformer.transform(SimpleTransformer.java:49)
 at com.mavenir.data.migration.migrators.Migrator.migrate(Migrator.java:56)
 at com.mavenir.data.migration.DataMigrator.main(DataMigrator.java:44

Comment: Is SimpleTransformer your code ?

Comment: yes.....its pointing to the line where i am casting inputBean.getBeanClass().cast(inputObj);  where inputobj is one resultant row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't seem to use any result transformer (such as `AliasToBeanResultTransformer`) for your query. So, since it uses a projection list, your query returns a `List<Object[]>`. there is no way Hibernate can know that it must return instances of your bean class. Either you transform the `List<Object[]>` into what you want explicitely, or you use a ResultTransformer.

Comment: i tried using transformer... But now i am getting nullPointer Exception where i am using getmethod.invoke Method getMethod = inputBean.getGetterMethod(propertyName1);  Object retObj = getMethod.invoke(inputObj, new Object[0]);

Comment: Can any1 help me here......??? please tell me how i can get rid of nullPointerException

Comment: The message of the exception tells you exactly where it happens. It's in your code, and we don't have it. How could we help?